# How to call API method that accepts XML in ASP.NET Core Web APIs?

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

The API Method I am calling is:

```
[HttpPost("PostXml")]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public Reservation PostXml([FromBody] Reservation res) =>
    repository.AddReservation(new Reservation
    {
        Name = res.Name,
        StartLocation = res.StartLocation,
        EndLocation = res.EndLocation
    });
```

The client code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddReservationByXml(Reservation reservation)
{
    Reservation receivedReservation = new Reservation();
    
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        StringContent content = new StringContent(ConvertObjectToXMLString(reservation), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

        using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:8888/api/Reservation/PostXml", content))
        {
            string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            receivedReservation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Reservation>(apiResponse);
        }
    }
    return View(receivedReservation);
}

string ConvertObjectToXMLString(object classObject)
{
    string xmlString = null;
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(classObject.GetType());
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, classObject);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        xmlString = new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd();
    }
    return xmlString;
}
```

I am failing to call the API method and getting the error:

> 400One or
> more validation errors
> occurred.https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1|f5452728-4c49abe4d88e559e.1.8095e7c1_An
> error occurred while deserializing input
> data.

What is wrong here?

Comment: look at Reservation class/structure definition, is there any fields/properties validation attributes, that constrains domains

Comment: are you sure, your api method is returning json data?

Answer (score 0):

You got error from this line

```
    receivedReservation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Reservation>(apiResponse);
```

Please check the validation of your `Reservation` Model and detail the `values` you past
and the `content` of error you got.

Comment: Hi, @yogihosting, please let us know if you have  updated information on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML request should be with the correct case as the c# class. XML is case sensitive.

Try this code.

```
        XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Reservation));

        System.IO.StringWriter sww = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
        xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, reservation);
        var xml = sww.ToString();
```